# How to draw a polygon of n sides, m times

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I'm new in Python programming and I'm having a task to develop a simple program that draws a polygon of n sides, m times, making the leftmost edge of the next polygon touch the rightmost edge of the previous polygon. The code below draws a polygon depending on the number of sides the user inputs and the number of times the polygon should appear.

```
import turtle

def myTurtle():
  num_side = raw_input("Enter the number of sides: " )
  num_shap = raw_input("Enter the number of shapes: " )
  num_sides = int(num_side)
  num_shape = int(num_shap)
  window = turtle.Screen()
  window.bgcolor("red")

  polygon = turtle.Turtle()
  polygon.penup()
  polygon.goto(-200, 200)
  polygon.pendown()
  side_length = 60
  angle = 360.0 // num_sides 
  n = 0

  for j in range(0, num_shape):
    polygon.forward(side_length)
    for i in range(num_sides):
        polygon.pencolor("black")
        polygon.forward(side_length)
        polygon.right(angle)
    n += side_length    
window.exitonclick()

myTurtle()
```

The problem I'm having now is to make the next polygon go next to the previous polygon.

---

I have been able to come up with a better but still not a perfect solution. Just some polygon that are touching each other. How can i achieve this?

```
import turtle, math

def find_lenth(radius, sides):
  angle = float(360 / sides)
  otherangle = float((180 - angle) / 2)
  radangle = float(angle * (math.pi / 180))
  radangle2 = float(otherangle * (math.pi/180))
  angles = math.sin(radangle) / math.sin(radangle2)
  lenth = radius * angles
  return lenth    

def myTurtle():
  num_side = raw_input("Enter the number of sides: " )
  num_shap = raw_input("Enter the number of shapes: " )
  num_sides = int(num_side)
  num_shape = int(num_shap)
  window = turtle.Screen()
  window.bgcolor("red")
  polygon = turtle.Turtle()
  radius = 60
  side_length = find_lenth(radius, num_sides)
  angle = 360.0 // num_sides 
  delta = radius*2  #this value you must count
  colors = ['blue','white','black','green']
  for i in range(num_shape):
    polygon.penup()
    polygon.goto(-400+delta*i, 200)
    polygon.pendown()
    polygon.pencolor(colors[i%4])
    n = 0
    for j in range(num_sides):
      polygon.forward(side_length)
      polygon.right(angle)
  window.exitonclick()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  myTurtle()
```

Comment: Use a variable max_x to remember the maximum x coordinate of a polygon (it you can obtain that with turtle graphics) Then start with y = 0 and x = max_x for the next polygon etc..Alternatively first draw the upper halves from each polygon as one uninterrupted line and then go back to your starting point and draw all lower halves as another uninterrupted line.

Comment: **1)** Are you doing this on python 2 or python 3? **2)** You can get the current co-ordinates of the turtle by using the `turtle.position()` method. **3)** Change your angle calculation to `angle = 360.0 / num_sides`, otherwise it will round off angles for polygons where the side number isn't a factor of 360. Eg, see what happens with your current code when you tell it to draw 7-sided polygons. **4)** You need to use `penup()` in between your polygons.

Comment: i'm doing it on python 2x

Answer (score -1):

This code will draw you some polygons. For moving pointer to the right value of pixels you need to count it.

```
import turtle

def myTurtle():
    num_side = raw_input("Enter the number of sides: " )
    num_shap = raw_input("Enter the number of shapes: " )
    num_sides = int(num_side)
    num_shape = int(num_shap)
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")
    polygon = turtle.Turtle()
    side_length = 60
    angle = 360.0 // num_sides 
    delta = side_length*3  #this value you must count
    colors = ['blue','white','black','green']
    for i in range(num_shape):
        polygon.penup()
        polygon.goto(-400+delta*i, 200)
        polygon.pendown()
        polygon.pencolor(colors[i%4])
        n = 0
        for j in range(num_sides):
            polygon.forward(side_length)
            polygon.right(angle)
    window.exitonclick()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myTurtle()
```

Comment: Your polygons aren't touching. Also, your angle calculation is incorrect.

Comment: the polygons aren't touching. A bit explanations again, if the user enters 5 for number of sides and 2 for number of polygons. It should draw a polygon of 5 sides and the second polygon should torch the edge of the first polygon.

Comment: It is authors angles. And I write what must be counted to make it touching (next it is math question, not python). I could count it but I think author asked for python help, not math.

Comment: The major aim is to achieve the polygon's touching one another in Python.  If using math makes it possible, HOW?

Comment: It is a tough problem for drawing in gerenal because your work with discrete values. If you define the boundaries of the problem (maybe not on polygons you need?) I could tell you the direction to dig in.

Comment: An idea just came up but don't know how i can implement that, If i have the polygons been drawn in a square of specified. I think the problem with the initial code is that it draw with a fixed length, so, if it works for polygon of 5 sides, it won't work for polygon of 6 sides

Comment: Read some info about regular polygons. I think it helps you to understand how you need to change delta. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon